# Protractor - Find delete button in <tr> with respect to <td> in other <tr>

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, end-to-end

In the web page, we have a number of rows (with row nested to it). The below code is a snippet for one such row.

```
<tr ng-repeat="abc" class="alpha">
<td class="one ng-binding">
    Apple
</td>
<td class="filters">
    <table class = "wood">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="xyz" class="xeta">
                <td class="two">...</td>
                <td class="three">...</td>
                <td class="four">
                    <button type="button" class="remove" ng-click="vm.delete">
                    .....
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>        
</td>
```

I am having difficulty in finding the way (element(by....)) to access the delete button for the apple's row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css:

```
td button.remove
```

or xpath:

```
//td/button[@class='remove']
```

If you have multiple filters you should add constraint for that section like:

```
.wood td button.remove
```

Answer (score 0):

If button is the only button on the page with class remove, You can select it using this:

```
var RemoveButton= element(by.css(".remove"));
```

If you have more use xpath:

```
var RemoveButton = element(by.xpath(".//td[@class='four']/button");
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the apple:

```
by.xpath("tr//td(@text='apple')")
```

Now get the enclosed td

```
by.xpath("tr//td(@text='apple')"). 
by.xpath("td.filters button[@class='remove']")
```

Comment: Hey, your code was very helpful the evolve the code needed for my solution, which is element(by.xpath("//tr/td[text()='Apple']/following-sibling::td[1]/table/tbody/tr[@class='xeta']/td[@class='four']/button"));